# image url not open on preview but thumbnail open may be stream issue

Tags: angular, preview

```
<!--only it work with thumbnail ,  not in case of doc.content.url
```

when we open with doc.content.url it does not open [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFqQO.png)
#may be steams issue
https://api.openage.in/drive/v1/api/files/63178c172650d20a74aa0fdc/streams?role-key=64feb6b9-ef8a-4b02-74f6-612dd5ecfb0e

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are uploading to a document store which does not support streaming the data

You may need to switch to any of the cloud file storage